# NFC communication between Android Kotlin app and Arduino

Tags: android, kotlin, arduino, nfc, nfc-p2p

I'm currently looking to transfer data between an Android app in Kotlin and an Arduino board with NFC (PN532).
I want to establish NFC communication, because my project requires scanning NFC tags.
I saw that it was necessary to turn more towards Bluetooth or wifi, but that would mean adding additional elements to the assembly and therefore having higher consumption, which I try to avoid.

I looked into NFC P2P (Beam) but it seems to me that Beam is no longer used.

I would like to know if it is possible to communicate using NFC like with Beam today?
If you have even just some leads, I'm interested.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using NFC to transfer data is not ideal, it is slow and unreliable, this is one of the reason it was removed from Android in favour of bluetooth/wifi direct.

BUT it is still possible with Android, if complicated and might be ok for small amounts of data.

You can use [Host Card Emulation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce) (HCE) where one side of the communication pretends to be a Type 4A NFC Tag and then you can read/write to it as a normal Tag (If you implement all the necessary protocol)

A working one directional example is at https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid

You don't specify the NFC hardware used on the Arduino but the NFC Reader might also be able to do HCE.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
I had tried HCE before, but didn't really understand how it worked.
After reading your example and others I found, I was able to solve my problem. (the Arduino program was not the right one and I didn't use the right AID..)
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The AID used does not really matter, as long on the reader and HCE device use the same one they will communicate with each other and then work within the available iso 7816-4 protocol then will work. The example given just uses the "Well Known" AID for the Ndef data format and then implements the correct responses for this standard data format. Using Ndef does help narrow down the flexibility to something that is well documented.

Comment: The problem with the AID was that I had not defined it on the Arduino, so obviously the communication was not happening… Thanks for the additional information.